# Preventing browser from leaking setup/screen information?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, security, privacy

Properties like [`MouseEvent.screenX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/screenX) encode more information about my setup than needed for almost all websites, but can easily be used for digital fingerprinting.

Assuming I run Chrome, Chromium (or a derivative), or Firefox: What are some ways (perhaps a plugin) to prevent this sort of data (i.e. hints about my custom setup) from leaking?

Comment: Googling `chrome prevent fingerprinting`, first three results contain 2 articles with instructions and Chrome plugin.

Comment: And they are in fact not useful except for https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/self-defense, which essentially says "abandon a custom setup".

The question is: are there non-nuclear solutions?
FWIW, despite Firefox saying that it prevents fingerprinting, it does not. I can still easily grab `screenX`, `Window.outerWidth`, etc.

Comment: As you have more info, it'd be a good idea to add it to your original question to focus it better. If for nothing else, but to prevent dunces like me from offering solutions you already are aware of :-)